# Can we query a Log analytics work-space in 2 different subscription but under a SINGLE AD TENANT, to get data?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines

In a situation where OMS/Loganalytics workspace sitting under 2 different subscription can we still query OMS workspace in different subscription using the same PowerShell subscription context?

Answer (score 0):

OMS Log Analytics Workspace is one resource in Azure and can exist only in one Subscription. It can get monitoring related data from multiple subscriptions. But the workspace itself will exist in one subscription only.

I have had various customer deployments, where the customer had multiple Azure subscriptions but only one OMS Log Analytics workspace to monitor all these subscriptions. You can then use the PowerShell context for the subscription where Log Analytics workspace exists.

You can find this subscription by navigating to your OMS Log Analytics workspace and checking the subscription section as shown below.

[image: Subscription Detail for the Log Analytics workspace]